# For loops and counting

Tags: c++

Sorry I am a very novice programmer and just learning. I've just been having one problem. I have been trying to get this to count the number of times the largest number has been displayed. But sometimes it has one more then it should. I changed some of the variables and moved it around. I've been stuck for about an hour.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int largeNumCount = 0;
    int largeNum = 1;
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));
    for (int x = 1; x <= 20; x++)
    {
        int randNum = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        cout <<  randNum << "  ";
        if (largeNum <= randNum)
        {
            largeNum = randNum;
            largeNumCount = 1;
        }
        if (largeNum == randNum)
        {
            largeNumCount++;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\nThe largest number: " << largeNum << " was found " << largeNumCount << " time(s)\n\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: should not be `else if ( largeNum == randNum)` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ( randNum > largeNum )
{
    largeNum = randNum;
    largeNumCount = 1;
}
else if ( randNum == largeNum )
{
    ++largeNumCount;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help! :D That makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: and change `int largeNum = 1;` to `int largeNum = 0;` or less than 0

Comment: @darkredninja : answer surely helped you but did you understand where actually you thought it to be wrong ?